# Regarding static collision resolution between two circles

Tags: c++, collision-resolution

I have some code that resolves the positions of two circles when they collide:

```
float fDist = sqrtf((c2->m_pos.x - c1->m_pos.x) * (c2->m_pos.x - c1->m_pos.x) + (c2->m_pos.y - c1->m_pos.y) * (c2->m_pos.y - c1->m_pos.y));
float fOverlap = 0.5f * (fDist - c1->m_radius - c2->m_radius);
   
c1->m_pos.x -= fOverlap * (c1->m_pos.x - c2->m_pos.x) / fDist;
c1->m_pos.y -= fOverlap * (c1->m_pos.y - c2->m_pos.y) / fDist;

c2->m_pos.x += fOverlap * (c1->m_pos.x - c2->m_pos.x) / fDist;
c2->m_pos.y += fOverlap * (c1->m_pos.y - c2->m_pos.y) / fDist;
```

However, I'm having the issue that, on large numbers of simulated circles, as the program "detection rate" slows down, `fDist` approaches (or even becomes) `0`. As a result, the circles in question are blasted off into infinity, rather than "glide" apart from each other as I intend on doing. Is there an alternative method of achieving this effect? Or does my simulation simply run too slowly?

For more context, I am following javidx9's [tutorial on circle collisions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPzyNOHY3A4).

Comment: Are you taking delta time into account? You can set an arbitrary minimum delta time to prevent small values. Also, are you filtering your radius overlaps to see if a collision can even exist before running your sqrt? You can do the radius check without doing the sqrt.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I will apply and play around with these ideas